# How do I insert a newline between chapter number and chapter title?

Tags: formatting, chapters, titlesec

How do I insert a newline between chapter number and chapter title to have:

```
chapter 1
Introduction

blahblah
```

My current code (using package `titlesec` and have a `\newline` before `\chaptertitlename` doesn't work) gives me only

```
chapter 1 Introduction

blahblah
```

The code:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}
    {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-35pt}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Use the `displaystyle` as an optional argument of `\titleformat`.

Comment: Why using `titlesec` at all? That's the default behaviour anyway...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: a]

Try this code.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display] % changed
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter }{0pt}{\Huge} % changed
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-35pt}{20pt}  % changed

\begin{document}
    
    \chapter{Introduction}
    
    \lipsum[1]
    
\end{document}
```